# Checking a coordinate in a two-dimensional array for a minefield game in C

Tags: c, dynamic-arrays

I'm writing a small minefield game. I implemented functions for initializing a minefield and deploying mines. Now I have to write a function that checks whether or not a specific coordinate contains mines. If a coordinate is free the state should be changed from UNKNOWN_FREE to KNOWN_FREE and return 0. If a coordinate contains a mine -- UNKNOWN_MINE to KNOWN_MINE and return 1. If a coordinate is outside the minefield -1 should be returned.

```
int checkPlace(const Field *f, unsigned int x, unsigned int y)
{

while (y < f->ysize && x < f->xsize){

if( ( f->places[y][x] = UNKNOWN_MINE ) ){
    f->places[y][x] = KNOWN_MINE;
    return 1;
}       
    else if ( (f->places[y][x] = UNKNOWN_FREE) ){
        f->places[y][x] = KNOWN_FREE;  
        return 0;
    }
}
return -1;
}
```

Now I get an error that for free positions 1 is returned instead of 0.

```
typedef enum {
    UNKNOWN_FREE,
    UNKNOWN_MINE,
    KNOWN_FREE,
    KNOWN_MINE
} State;

typedef struct {
    unsigned int xsize, ysize;
    State **places;
} Field;
```

I would really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 4):

You are using `=` which is the assignment operator. You need the comparison operator(`==`).

Change

```
if( ( f->places[y][x] = UNKNOWN_MINE ) ){
```

to

```
if( ( f->places[y][x] == UNKNOWN_MINE ) ){
```

and

```
else if ( (f->places[y][x] = UNKNOWN_FREE) ){
```

to

```
else if ( (f->places[y][x] == UNKNOWN_FREE) ){
```

Also, the extra parenthesis is not necessary.